# .eslintrc.js doesn't work with rules "off"

Tags: react-native, eslint, eslintrc

native and have a problem with configuring eslint.
This is my .eslintrc.js.

```
module.exports = {
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "jest": true,
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "node"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-use-before-define": "off",
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
        "node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax": ["error", {
            "version": ">=6.0.0",
            "ignores": ["modules", "destructuring"]
        }],
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
        "react/prop-types": "off",  
    }
};
```

In App.js,

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
```

I got the eslint error.

```
[eslint] Destructuring are not supported yet on Node 4.0.0. (node/no-unsupported-features) 
[eslint] 'navigation' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)
```

And also in In App.js,

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <UpArrow title="cancel" />
    <SecondsSpinner seconds={this.state.imageTime} changeImageTime={this.changeImageTime} />
    <DownArrow title="save" />
</View>
```

I got error

```
[eslint] JSX not allowed in files with extension '.js' (react/jsx-filename-extension)
```

So I

- turned off "react/prop-types",
- set  "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }]
- set "ignores": ["destructuring"].

But they dosen't work.
I don't know why and how to solve this.
Is there any other file to config eslint?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT1) "ignores": ["modules"] works. so weird.

EDIT2)  I am using vscode and got errors on the editor on and on, so I thought because of .eslintrc file.
But now I think it's problem of vscode. I set

```
"eslint.options": { "configFile": "/Users/com/vscode/AwesomeProject/.eslintrc.js" }
```

in Workspace Settings then it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
module.exports = {
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "jest": true,
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "node"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-use-before-define": 0,
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
        "node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax": ["error", {
            "version": ">=6.0.0",
            "ignores": ["modules", "destructuring"]
        }],
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
        "react/prop-types": 0,  
    }
};
```

Comment: gash I am using vscode and got errors on the editor on and on, so I thought because of .eslintrc file. But I think it's problem of vscode. I set "eslint.options": { "configFile": "/Users/com/vscode/AwesomeProject/.eslintrc.js" } in Workspace Settings then it works. Sorry for wrong question